# Does serving static files from multiple routes in Meteor implies to multiply /public installations?

Tags: file, url, meteor, routes, mapping

I am writing a Meteor application where I use jstree in several pages and in some modals.
Jstree itself uses some images (`32px.png`, `40px.png` and `throbber.gif`).

To let Meteor serve these files, I have copied the files in a `/public/jstree` directory, and patched accordingly the jstree standard stylesheet, and I import the patched css from my js. All fine.

So I have:

```
$ du -a public/
4   public/jstree/40px.png
8   public/jstree/32px.png
4   public/jstree/throbber.gif
20  public/jstree
24  public/
```

and

```
$ grep -E '32px.png|40px.png|throbber' imports/client/components/panel/jstree-style-abs-path.css 
  background-image: url("/jstree/32px.png");
  background: url("/jstree/throbber.gif") center center no-repeat;
  background: url("/jstree/32px.png") -100px -68px no-repeat;
  background: url("/jstree/32px.png") -260px -4px no-repeat;
  background-image: url("/jstree/32px.png");
  background-image: url("/jstree/32px.png");
  background: url("/jstree/throbber.gif") center center no-repeat;
  background: url("/jstree/32px.png") -103px -71px no-repeat;
  background: url("/jstree/32px.png") -263px -7px no-repeat;
  background-image: url("/jstree/32px.png");
  background-image: url("/jstree/32px.png");
  background: url("/jstree/throbber.gif") center center no-repeat;
  background: url("/jstree/32px.png") -96px -64px no-repeat;
  background: url("/jstree/32px.png") -256px 0px no-repeat;
  background-image: url("/jstree/32px.png");
    background-image: url("/jstree/40px.png");
    background-image: url("/jstree/40px.png");
    background-image: url("/jstree/40px.png");
    background-image: url("/jstree/40px.png");
    background: url("/jstree/40px.png") 0 -160px no-repeat;
    background: url("/jstree/40px.png") -40px -40px no-repeat;
```

and

```
import { jstree } from 'jstree';
import './jstree-style-abs-path.css';
import './panel.html';
```

That works fine as long I stay on `/` route or `/onelevel` route. I mean that I correctly see the images in the tree.

As soon I try to go to `/a/b` or `/a/b/c` route, I see in the Network pane of my Chromium browser that images are searched in `/a/jstree/32px.png` for a  `/a/b` route, or in `/a/b/jstree/32px.png` for a `/a/b/c` route! As a consequence, images are no more displayed.

[Edit]
Versions:

- Meteor 2.10.0
- kadira:blaze-layout       2.0.1
- ostrio:flow-router-extra  3.9.0

I have published a [very small application](https://github.com/trychlos/bug-mapping-url) to exhibit this behavior.

At the moment, I am a bit stuck here.
IMHO, I believed that using an absolute path in the url of the css would prevent me from this type of behavior.
Do I must copy the resources for each and every route I expect to use ?
Any idea please ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What if you omit the first slash of the urls? Like `background-image: url("jstree/32px.png");`?

Comment: Amazing: behavior is the exact same! I don't understand what happens..

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I cannot do anything else than confirming the bug.

But, I publish here a server-side work-around:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use( function( req, res, next ){
    const indexOf = req.url.indexOf( '/jstree/' );
    if( indexOf > 0 ){
        const newurl = req.url.substring( indexOf );
        console.log( 'WebApp redirecting', req.url, 'with', newurl );
        res.writeHead( 301, {
            Location: newurl
        });
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you think this is really a bug, would you mind to open a ticket in the Meteor repo at GitHub: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/

Comment: Done as #12524.